# Is it possible to adapt unique_ptr for use in plain c?

Tags: c++, c, unique-ptr

Is it possible to adapt unique_ptr for plain c?

Perhaps if there is a way of simulating calls to a home made "constructor/destructor" when calling malloc/free?

Is it doable? Or is it just a silly idea?

Comment: Eh, Mark and I seem to have two distinct interpretations. Are you trying to wrap C code inside unique_ptr, or are you trying to use unique_ptr from inside C?

Comment: @MSalters I am trying to see if it is possible to use unique_ptr from inside C.

Comment: If you want this kind of behavior, why are you programming in C?? You'll get the same bloat as if you used a higher-level language and none of the niceties...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of a "smart pointer" is to do certain tasks automatically on destruction. Since C doesn't have destructors there's no way to accomplish this except with explicit function calls - but that's how you deallocate memory in C already.

You could possibly make a list of pointers that need to be freed and do them all at the same time with a single function call.

Answer (score 3):

No, not in plain C. You can do something similar with the `cleanup` GCC attribute (it is not standard):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void scope_leaving(int* p) 
{
    printf("Leaving scope.\n");
    // this is essentially your "destructor"
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    printf("Before x is declared.\n");
    {
        int x __attribute__((cleanup (scope_leaving)));
        x = 42;
    }
    printf("Scope was left.\n");
}
```

As you would expect, the output is this:

```
Before x is declared.
Leaving scope.
Scope was left.
```

With this, you can implement a pointer emulates the RAII semantics of `unique_ptr`, maybe using a macro for easier declaration. There is more to `unique_ptr` than that, but I'm not sure from your question if you want other aspects besides RAII.

Answer (score 2):

On second reading, there's nothing that prevents your C structures from starting with a `void(*)()` pointer. If you have a `custom_malloc(size_t size, void(*deleter)()` which sets the pointer, your `custom_free(void*)` can subsequently call that deleter. This is similar to a `virtual` destructor from C++. However, the second part of `std::unique_ptr` is a `delete`'d copy constructor. You can't do that in C.

Answer (score 0):

In order to implemented unique_ptr, you need two things:

1. assignment operator which transfers ownership;
2. destructor for when unique_ptr goes out-of-scope.

In order to implement (1), since C does not allow you to have function overloading, you need to "discipline" yourself and always call a custom assignment function or macro. C cannot force you to always have ownership transferred.

As for (2), GCC provides an [extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#Variable-Attributes): you are allow to assign a "cleanup" function, which is called once a variable gets out of scope. This can be used to implement a destructor for your unique_ptr.

Comment: In fact, `unique_ptr` does *not* have an assignment operator that transfers ownership (only from an rvalue reference) – otherwise it would be inherently unsafe, like the deprecated `auto_ptr`.